# jQuery AutoComplete error: "s is undefined". How can I resolve this?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using [jquery.autocomplete.js](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete), and the following JS:

```
$("#Search").autocomplete("/uk/Search/AutoComplete",
{
    dataType: 'json',
    parse: function (data) {
        var rows = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            rows[i] = { data: data[i], value: data[i].Tag, result: data[i].Tag };
        }
        return rows;
    }, max: 20,
    formatItem: function (row, i, max) {
        return row.Tag;
    },
    width: 300,
    minChars: 4,
    highlight: false,
    multiple: false
});
```

This all works fine, and I can see that there is a server round-trip going on, and the result I expect is in the `data` variable.

The problem I have is that I can see in the FireFox Error Console that there is an error stating `s is undefined`.

It's failing on the following:

```
$.Autocompleter.Cache = function(options) {

    var data = {};
    var length = 0;

    function matchSubset(s, sub) {
        if (!options.matchCase)
            s = s.toLowerCase(); // this is where it fails
        var i = s.indexOf(sub);
        if (options.matchContains == "word") {
            i = s.toLowerCase().search("\\b" + sub.toLowerCase());
        }
        if (i == -1) return false;
        return i == 0 || options.matchContains;
    };
```

Why would this be failing? Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Are you passing in a variable for s?

Comment: what is `Autocompleter.Cache`? Its not part of jQuery UI...

Comment: @Tim, I don't do anything with `s`. I don't know what that variable is, and I don't pass anything for it

Comment: Post your ajax response JSON, May be issue in that.

Comment: What do you mean you "don't do anything with `s`? Isn't that your code?

Comment: @RoToRa, no. `s` exists in the jquery.autocomplete.js file

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time...

When I get the message "[something] is undefined" it is because my JSON response object(s) contains an illegal character in the JSON or the JSON isn't formatted correctly...making the object return as undefined.

Please post your JSON so we can look further.